# How to configure terminal like this?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I found a terminal theme in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wo4b9FPEiHk&list=PL-J9GXT0E7ALwbi339_AsbGvKbdIw52Vf&index=1) @ ~7min. I love it but I don't know how to configure terminal like this. Would you please help me? 
It seems this Ubuntu is running in Windows Linux Subsystem with puppet. There are 2 things I want to set up.

1. As boxed in the bottom left, the terminal automatically switches the command to the next line to the username. Also, the font seems different from the default in Ubuntu.
2. As boxed in the upper right, those 2 icons provide many useful utilities for presentation. For example, the pen-tip icon enables drawing annotation similar in the edge browser. How can I get them too?

[image: Image here]

Comment: See the video at 6:09 min when narrator shows task window. The right pen icon probably for a stylus for a touchscreen. And the command window (through ssh) is `zsh` or customise with `.bashrc`. But it is hard to tell which specific customisation was used because there are many scripts avaialable.

Comment: Please post it. I have found the right theme (bira), but I wouldn't without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [video](https://youtu.be/wo4b9FPEiHk) is a tutorial for gem5. Probably the narrator used tablet and stylus to write on screen. See the [video at 6:08 minute](https://youtu.be/wo4b9FPEiHk?list=PL-J9GXT0E7ALwbi339_AsbGvKbdIw52Vf&t=368), narrator used OBS to broadcast the video. So, the pen icon at upper right is probably for that stylus.

The command prompt screen was customized with [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) shell and [oh-my-zsh](/questions/tagged/oh-my-zsh) theme. The theme is [bira.zsh-theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/bira.zsh-theme) (as mentioned by @yi-shen). Here are the steps to install that theme:

- Install `zsh` in WSL: `apt install zsh`
- Install `oh-my-zsh` configuration files:

```sh
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

- Edit `.zshrc` file to select `bira` theme, add this line: `ZSH_THEME="bira"`

Restart bash.exe/wsl.exe to effect the changes. If the colors/fonts are not visible in Command Prompt then use [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty) (uses mintty). Find more information about these instructions in [oh-my-zsh repository](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).